# "Error : Use of undeclared type MessagingDelegate" in Firebase messaging

Tags: ios, swift3, appdelegate, firebase-notifications

I have updated my firebase messaging pod recently and followed the Quickstart guide of Firebase to perform necessary changes of upgradation.

I added the new `extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate` extension but getting certain errors.

[image]

Answer (score 48):

add `import FirebaseMessaging` at the top of the page would resolve the issue

Comment: And why is that?? It's odd that this isn't mentioned in the official documentation?

Answer (score 7):

it is about the version of firebase ,in this case change `MessagingDelegate` to `FIRMessagingDelegate` and the function [START refresh_token] from

```
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken 
  fcmToken: String) {
     print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")

}
```

to

```
func messaging(_ messaging: FIRMessaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken 
 fcmToken: String) {
    print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")
}
```

and last

```
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: 
  MessagingRemoteMessage) {
    print("Received data message: \(remoteMessage.appData)")
 }
```

to

```
func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(_ remoteMessage: 
     FIRMessagingRemoteMessage) {
    print("Received data message: \(remoteMessage.appData)")
}
```

complete answer is

```
extension AppDelegate : FIRMessagingDelegate {
    func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(_ remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage) {
    print("Received data message: \(remoteMessage.appData)")
}

// [START refresh_token]

func messaging(_ messaging: FIRMessaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")
}}
```

Comment: Please add some explanations to your answer, as it is right now peoples who could en up here in the future probably won't know what to do with this code.

Comment: i have updated my answer , thank you for your suggestion

Comment: That's better :)

Answer (score 3):

**For Swift 4 to up:**

What version of Firebase are you using? According to the documentation, class names changes for Firebase 4.0.0 in Swift. So FIRMessagingDelegate, is now MessagingDelegate, and so on. See the migration guide [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/naming-migration-guide)

Answer (score 2):

`MessagingDelegate` is undeclared type, says the error. Make sure you're importing the Firebase Framework, like so:

`import Firebase`

If importing the Firbease framework gives you an error `no such module Firebase`, then you need to fix that first, that `no such module Firebase` error. How to fix that? You need to check the version of your Firebase pod against the version of your Swift language. Perhaps the Firebase version you have uses the Swift 4.0 while your project uses Swift 3.0.

To make sure you're installing the pod dedicated for Swift 3.0, add can add a checker for build settings of each pod to your Podfile. Also make sure you're installing `Messaging` framework of Firebase, like so:

```
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'

post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: import Firebase itself giving me error 'no such module Firebase' error ; which is why I added import FirebaseCore and import FirebaseInstanceID

Comment: it isn't working; I downgraded the version of Firebase to 4.0.0 which supports Swift3 but it didn't work. Still getting the same error

Comment: Have you done the ritual? Cmd+Shift+K and Cmd+Shift+AltOption+K? :)

Comment: Yes Already did that multiple times.  It's just that I have added pod 'Firebase', '~> 4.0.0' in podfile but while installation it showed in terminal as "Installing Firebase 4.0.4 (was 4.3.0)". do you feel it has any impact to this

Comment: I think so. Can you check out my edited answer, I've added some checker for you.

Comment: So basically, MessagingDelegate belongs to FirebaseMessaging. I tired adding import FirebaseMessaging instead of import Firebase and it worked. Now tell me one thing, the notification from console sending for single device; does work without APNs certificate or not?

Comment: You always need APNs certificate for remote push notifications :) If my answer helped you out, you might want to select this as the `answer`.

Answer (score 1):

Update the podfile using `pod update` and if pod update is failed to update, delete the **podfile.lock** and run `pod install`

Answer (score 0):

After updating the FirebaseMessageing to the 7.0.0 version, I've gotten the error so I had to chagne the `didReceiveRegistrationToken` function in this way:

```
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
     guard let fcmToken = fcmToken else { return }
     print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")
}
```